# How to search for NaNs in a loop?

Tags: python

I've created a list than continues NaN values. I want to be able to count these NaN values in a For loop and add them to a variable so I can count the total number of Nan values, does anyone have any ideas for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` should be the only value returning false on self equality:

```py
nan_count = sum(1 for value in my_list if value != value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count, you get it with

```
import numpy as np
my_arr = np.array(my_list)
count = (my_arr != my_arr).sum()
```